Auth0 SDK Integration: Issues with Redirecting Back to Android App
I’ve integrated the Android SDK into my project and followed the documented steps. The login prompt appears, and authentication seems successful, but the app isn’t redirecting back afterward.
In the sample app, I noticed both “Success Login” and “Success Exchange” statuses, but in my project, only “Success Login” appears.

The app remains stuck on the page without redirecting back to the Android app.


After spending 4-5 days on the issue,
Issue :
After authentication, Auth0 calls the callback URL. If the URL's scheme isn't correctly identified by the project, the callback won't be triggered, causing the app to remain stuck on the same page. This was the issue.
I discovered the problem was with the callback URL:
(scheme)://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/android/YOUR_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME/callback
The issue was that the (scheme) name wasn't unique to the project I was working on. While it worked in demos (since the scheme was unique for those), it wasn't considered unique for the project.
The solution was to update the callback with a unique scheme name that could correctly identify the project.
